# React native and webassembly issues

Tags: react-native, webassembly

We wrote an algorithm using `rust` and we compiled the code to `web assembly`
we want to integrate those functions into a `react native` app,
so i took the compiled folder that contain `.wasm` it shows.

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./fn_op.wasm` from
> `assets/libs/ofs_wasm/index.js`

How can i resolve this issue with react native and how to integrate `.wasm` files into it
is there a configuration that i can override same as the case with react-cli for `webpack`

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @strdr4605 yes as we found that react native is not web so we cannot run `webaassembly` on it, so we used rust swift wrapper same thing for java then connecting this to react native i think they used C to communicate between.

Comment: True. RN is not a WASM runtime. Run it on a WebView would work but could be slow.